# How to control lock granularity?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex

I am reading the book of `CPP-Concurrency-In-Action-2ed-2019`.
In chapter 3.2.8, the author explains how to control lock granularity, with the example:

```cpp
void get_and_process_data()
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> my_lock(the_mutex);
  some_class data_to_process = get_next_data_chunk();
  my_lock.unlock();  // 1
  result_type result = process(data_to_process);
  my_lock.lock();    // 2 
  write_result(data_to_process,result);
}
```

This code manually calls `lock` and `unlock` to reduce the locking time.
What confuses me is that `data_to_process` must be a value copied from `get_next_data_chunk()`, whereas if I lock it all the time in function `get_and_process_data()`, `get_next_data_chunk()` could simply return a reference or pointer to the target data:

```cpp
void get_and_process_data()
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> my_lock(the_mutex);
  some_class& data_to_process = get_next_data_chunk();
  data_to_process = process(data_to_process);
}
```

If `data_to_process`'s value copy is much more expensive than `process(data_to_process)` costs, is the first design achieving the opposite effect?

Comment: Yes, "it depends".  :-)  Presumably, `process` takes some time (that's why you don't want to hold the lock). So you have to consider if copying or processing takes the most time.

Comment: if you don't unlock for `process` then you can never process more than one chunk at a time

Comment: From given amount of data/code I would say locks here are probably needed inside of `get_next_data_chunk` and `write_result` and can be removed from `get_and_process_data`. Note that shared state here is not shown in this example, so reasons why mutex is needed is also hidden.

Comment: What you are bumping into here is one of the big headaches when trying to use threads to optimize something: Everything is a tradeoff and sometimes the ones you can see and think off are not the most important ones. It absolutely happens that somebody implements a new cool parallelization algorithm, that totally works and speeds everything up on paper, only for it to actually run slower in reality. That is why in many cases the only advice that can be given is: Try it and measure if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

> If `data_to_process`'s value copy is much more expensive than `process(data_to_process)` costs, is the first design achieving the opposite effect?

Yes, you are correct about that. If we use hugely expensive copy constructors in `get_and_process_data()`, then we might pay a greater price than `data_to_process`.

However, this is almost never a problem in practice because of indirection. The objects that go into the thread-safe queue are usually not full copies of the data, but handles to the data. For the purpose of thread-safety, we don't really care whether each thread has ownership over some object (or a copy of it), we only care about preventing two threads from running into a data race by accessing the same data concurrently.

For example:

```cpp
void get_and_process_data()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> my_lock(the_mutex);
    some_class data_to_process = get_next_data_chunk();
    my_lock.unlock();  // 1
    result_type result = process(data_to_process);
    my_lock.lock();    // 2 
    write_result(data_to_process, result);
}
```

In this code, the cost can be controlled by what `get_next_data_chunk()` returns:

- `some_class = std::array<int, HUGE>` would be bad, because the cost of copying might outweight the cost of `process`
- `some_class = std::span<int>` would be fine, because while we don't own the data, we can still make sure that the span of data isn't accessed concurrently
- `some_class = int` works the same; we might not distribute the data or pointer to threads, but an index into some array which is stored elsewhere
- `some_class = std::unique_ptr<int[]>` is also fine, and means that our thread actually obtains ownership; we may have to add extra `std::move`s to make this code work though
- `some_class = std::shared_ptr<int[]>` has the most overhead of all smart pointers, but might let us resolve some complicated issues with multiple threads having ownership over data

In summary, you are right in principle, however, the problem is easily solved by adding one level of indirection, typically through a (smart) pointer or span. The cost of one extra indirection is trivial compared to the overhead of starting up threads, and synchronizing them.